# Find the total disk usage not including files containing a string

Tags: find, disk-usage

I am trying to get the disk usage of the `owncloud` directory except not including the files and dirs containing the string nobackup in the name/dir.

This is my command so far :

```
find . -type f -not -regex '.+?nobackup.*'  -exec du -c {} +
```

But it gives me a false total when used on the cloud dir, on a test dir it works just fine.

Comment: You're using `+?` which is defined as "undefined behaviour" in a POSIX ERE, but has a special meaning in other types of regex, like PCRE. GNU `find` for example does not support PCRE. Which OS and/or version of `find`?

Comment: Do your results change if you use `find . -type f -not -name "*nobackup*"  -exec du -c {} + `?

Comment: i am running Ubuntu 14.04.1 with find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2

`if i use : find . -type f -not -name "*nobackup*" -exec du -c {} +` it gives also the files in a dir called nobackup.

Comment: The strange thing is that the initial find command lists the files well but it looks like something gets lost in the du command . is there a limit on content that can be conducted true this -exec ? it looks like some get lost ( there are about 120000 files in this path )

Comment: @mr.spuratic emacs re's are used by default with `-regex` in `find`. `+?` is the [non greedy +](http://www.emacswiki.org/RegularExpression), though not particularly sure why the distinction is needed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use either `find ... -exec COMMAND {} +` or `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 COMMAND`, `xargs` or `find` will be build a list of filename arguments no longer than each command’s defined buffer space (bounded by `ARG_MAX`). If the buffer space is exhausted, each command will pass the list of filename arguments to `COMMAND` and start creating a new list. That process will repeat as many times as necessary, until there are no more filenames, at which point, the list of filenames that was being built will be passed to `COMMAND` a final time.

So if you're not expecting your `find` command to return a large number of filenames

```
find . -type f -not -regex '.+?nobackup.*' -exec du -c {} +
```

may be sufficient. If you are and your `du` supports `--files0-from` you can use, `--files0-from=-` it to read null-terminated `files` directly from `stdin` (`du` considers `-` to mean coming from `stdin`)

```
find . -type f -not -regex '.+?nobackup.*' -print0 | du -c --files0-from=-
```

*Note: `--files0-from` is not specified by `posix`, but it should be extended in the most recent `gnu du` versions. If your implementation has it omitted you will most likely have to loop over the results of `find` in some way and add up the totals in the loop.*